# If held here I'm dangerous

Tags: riddle

In more ways than one,

My end brings a start,

But can also bring the end itself.

I end all fun,

But I only ever began with grief.

Comment: It's been a long time this questions is asked. But no right answer yet? Or could you please tick it some of below are right one? I am willing to see the answer :D

Comment: OK, not sure about what I should do, since the answer wasn't exactly correct, but was close.

Comment: OK, I accepted the closest answer, however the slight additions are in my answer below.

Comment: Glad for right answers tick, I just think it is okay for "Gun" or "Guns", as it is difficult to find someone or some answer to write definitely what you're thinking in your mind. Thanks! @Resquiens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> GUNS

In more ways than one

> Guns is plural.

My end brings a start

> Start begins with an S, the end of GUNS.

But can also bring the end itself.

> Not sure - maybe that guns can kill people?

I end all fun,

> Guns can end fun (unless the fun is a paintball war)...

But I only ever began with grief.

> GUNS starts with a G, the beginning of grief, and they can cause grief.

Comment: You got it... (Well practically). I'm not sure how you did since you interpreted the hints in a slightly different way than I thought you might. I will post the solution I had in mind so you can compare!

Comment: @Resquiens I saw your comment on rand al'thor's answer, so I knew it included something with letters - "my end," "I only ever began," etc.

Comment: I won't add an explanation of my answer just yet, since I think there's lots of "solutions" within the riddle still to be found. Here's a point: your answer was correct, but the bit about being plural isn't what I had in mind - although it does fit in that sense.

Comment: @Resquiens Are you going to accept this answer, or is it not close enough yet on the explanations? Because I can see how to improve one or two of them...

Comment: Not going to accept it just yet, since there's still a lot more to discover ;)

Comment: Note: answer is 'Gun' not 'Guns' (see my answer below)

Answer (score 5):

### Credit to mdc32 for the answer, but here are more explanations

The answer is:

> GUN.

*If held here I'm dangerous* (title)

> Holding a gun by its barrel (say) can be a dangerous and stupid thing to do. Also G, U, and N all appear in the word "dangerous".

*In more ways than one,*

> This could be a reference to the fact that "gun" is a bit like "one" with an extra G on the beginning (at least phonetically). Also each of the succeeding lines has more than one interpretation: letterplay and metaphor.

*My end brings a start,*

> The end of "gun" is N, which is the commonest letter in the word "beginning". Also the abolition of guns might lead to a fresh new start for humanity.

*But can also bring the end itself.*

> That letter N is also the central letter in "end". Alternatively, abolishing guns in one place might lead to the end of that society if people in other places still had guns.

*I end all fun,*

> The word "gun" ends with the same letters as "fun". Also guns tend to end fun (unless they're water-pistols maybe).

*But I only ever began with grief.*

> The word "gun" starts with the same letter as "grief". Also guns often cause grief.

---

### First attempt

> STING?

*In more ways than one,*

> The letter **S** is used to pluralise, suggesting "more than one".

*My end brings a start,*

> The end of the word "start" is the letter **T**.

*But can also bring the end itself.*

> The letter just after the word "end" is **I**. (OK, my reasoning is weak for this line, but I is the only letter that fits with the rest.)

*I end all fun,*

> The final letter of "fun" is **N**.

*But I only ever began with grief.*

> The first letter of "grief" is **G**.

Comment: Nice thinking - your reasoning actually does fit for a lot of the lines and is quite creative - although the actual answer is different to what you suggest. Here's a tip: your solution METHOD was partially correct.

Comment: @Resquiens I guess the last two letters are correct and the first and third (and probably the second) are wrong?

Comment: Can't give too much more away, you'll have to wait a bit ;)

Comment: @randal'thor Your answer is so cool. Don't know if you've noticed, but it can be also matched to the meaning of the riddle - bee sting, death of the bee, allergy, death of the victim and so on. +1

Comment: Thanks dmg! :-) The intended answer is possibly even cooler: I've come up with a double meaning for every line. @Resquiens howzat?

Comment: @rand al'thor Very good :) You've worked out almost everything and this is indeed the correct answer. Last two lines are perfect. I will post my intended answer so you can compare, although saying that seeing both your own and mcdc32's answer's have opened my eyes to how widely the riddle can be interpreted - says a lot about open minded thinking and its benefits. Also, well done on noticing the title :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer I had in mind:

In more ways than one,

> *Literally* in more ways than one (see next sentence)

My end brings a start,

> The end of a gun can bring the start of the race. Also, considering its "in more ways than one", the end of a gun can also bring a start in the sense of being startled. The end of a gun is where the bullet exits.

But can also bring the end itself.

> Guns can end lives.

I end all fun,

> Two senses: first is that shooting somebody is fairly unpleasant. Secondly, this is a letter line: the end of 'all fun' is 'un'. Couple this with the next sentence.

But I only ever began with grief.

> The word gun begins with 'g'. Coupled with the ending 'un' from the previous line this spells 'gun'. Also, in another sense, guns were invented by people who intended them to cause trouble (for the most part).

BONUS:

> Kudos if you found this: the title can also be called the 'head' of a document. "If I'm held here I'm dangerous". If a gun is held at somebody's head...

Comment: The bonus is really nice!